# Formatting multiple BooleanFields as a single Select widget

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

The database im working with has several boolean fields where only ever one of them should be true at a time.
I want to format these as a Select widget, so that I can list each boolean field as a choice and False will be returned for all of the boolean fields except for the selected option.

I got each of them individually working as checkboxes (I commented those out), and I was able to make a select widget that is displaying correctly in the view (`client_type`), but I cannot accomplish the above.

Here's the relevant section of my models.py:

```
class DomCase(models.Model):
    plaintiff = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    defendant = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)

class DomCaseForm(ModelForm):
    client_type = ChoiceField(choices=(('', '----'),('plaintiff', 'Plaintiff'),('defendant','Defendant')), widget=Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'client_type'}))

    class Meta:
        model = DomCase

        widgets = {
            #'plaintiff': CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'custom-control-input', }),
            #'defendant': CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'custom-control-input', }),
        }

        # Dynamically Create Form Fields based on widget details
        fields = []
        for widget in widgets:
            fields.append(widget)
        fields = tuple(fields)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved my problem!

I ended up adding those working checkboxes back in and hiding them with `display: none;`, then I used jQuery to dynamically uncheck and check the boxes depending on the value of the select box.

I changed my checkbox widgets to the following:

```
        widgets = {
            'plaintiff': CheckboxInput(attrs={'style': 'display: none;'}),
            'defendant': CheckboxInput(attrs={'style': 'display: none;'}),
        }
```

And added the following jQuery to my template to handle the interaction:

```
    $('#client_type').change(function() {
        if ($('#client_type').val() == "defendant") {
            $('#id_defendant').prop("checked", true);
            $('#id_plaintiff').prop("checked", false);
        }
        else if ($('#client_type').val() == "plaintiff") {
            $('#id_defendant').prop("checked", false);
            $('#id_plaintiff').prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $('#id_defendant').prop("checked", false);
            $('#id_plaintiff').prop("checked", false);
        }
    });
```